# Why Uniformity of subpixel in image analysis ensures correctness

Tags: image

I don't know if its right place to ask this question.

I was working on particle tracking of series of pictures (.tiff) of colloids. And I was Using [trackpy](http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.5.0/tutorial/walkthrough.html) in python.

The code gives me the position of particles to subpixel accuracy.
[image: code snippets]

There is another step involved is of checking the subpixel accuracy. In this method we check the uniformity in the decimal part of the position

> a quick way to check for subpixel accuracy is to check that the decimal part of the x and/or y positions are evenly distributed. Trackpy provides a convenience plotting function for this called subpx_bias

[image]

Mask size is more or less the diameter of the particle.

**I am not getting how does evenly distribution of decimal part ensures that we are on the right track?
And how a dip shows that we are wrong somewhere?**

You can also refer to [Eric weeks](http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks//idl/tracking.html) website. on this website, it is briefly mentioned that

> One failure mode is if the length scale in the feature is made too small, then all the x and y coords get 'rounded off' to the nearest pixel value. The above command plots a histogram of the fractional part of the x-coords of the image. The physically distributed positions should be random -- giving a flat histogram. If the histogram has two peaks (near 0 and 1), set the size parameter in 'feature' a little bigger, determine a new masscut, and repeat until everything is happy.

Answer (score 0):

If the subpixels are not roughly evenly distributed then this means (among others) that certain decimal values are more prevalent than others and this can lead to **large gaps** in tracking the particle (gaps which can be larger than the particle's size).

So this amounts to saying that the outcome is not very precise.

On the other hand, basic *continuity of motion* requires that decimal values should be evenly distributed on average.

For example imagine the subpixels have a prevalence of `0.1` and `0.9` decimal values. So for a particle of size `1` its positions may vary by more than 2 pixels (eg `1.1-2.9`) so this creates inaccurate trackings on average.